# it is possible to pass a json object for a request get what I am trying and I miss the following error

Tags: java, json, rest, post, get

it is possible to pass a json object for a request get what I am trying and I miss the following error

```
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 46: https://localhost/Pro-Ing/rest/pedidos/prueba?{%22codigo%22:%22qwdasdas%22,%22id%22:%221%22}
```

this is the javascript method

```
function hola(){
var id= prompt('hola');
var id2= prompt('hola');
codigo = {};
codigo['codigo'] = id;
codigo['id'] = id2;
    $.ajax({
        url : "rest/pedidos/prueba",
        contentType : "application/json",
        dataType : "json",
        type : "GET",
        data : JSON.stringify(codigo),
        success : function(data) {
            jqmSimpleMessage('Paso');
        }
error : function(error) {
            if (error.status == 401) {
                desAuth();
            } else {
                jqmSimpleMessage("error -" + error.responseText);
            }
        },
        beforeSend : function(xhr, settings) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '
                    + getVCookie(getVCookie("userPro")));
        }
    });
}
```

this is the method of java that receives the object

```
@GET
@Path("/prueba")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response gendup(confirmacion usu,@Context SecurityContext securityContext) {
    registro(securityContext, 0, "");
    confirmacion confirmacion = null;
    Response.ResponseBuilder builder = null;
    return builder.build();
}
```

Comment: I think we need a bit more information.  It is hard to see where the exception is being thrown since there isn't a full stack trace.

The exception being thrown isn't caused by any of the javascript because it is a java exception.

If you changed your url to the following, it *might* work:  `https://localhost/Pro-Ing/rest/pedidos/prueba?%7b%22codigo%22:%22qwdasdas%22,%22id%22:%221%22%7d`

Answer (score 1):

```
Illegal character in query at index 46: https://localhost/Pro-Ing/rest/pedidos/prueba?{%22codigo%22:%22qwdasdas%22,%22id%22:%221%22}
```

Arrays in Java are zero based, so

```
01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456
https://localhost/Pro-Ing/rest/pedidos/prueba?{%22codigo%22:%22qwdasdas%22,%22id%22:%221%22
                                              ^
```

[RFC 3986, Appendix A](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-A) describes which characters are allowed in a query

```
query         = *( pchar / "/" / "?" )

pchar         = unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"

unreserved    = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
pct-encoded   = "%" HEXDIG HEXDIG
sub-delims    = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")"
              / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="
```

So the problem you are having here is that your java parser is strict about which characters are allowed in a URI, and neither left curly bracket `{` nor right curly bracket `}` are valid -- they need to be percent encoded as well.

```
https://localhost/Pro-Ing/rest/pedidos/prueba?%7B%22codigo%22:%22qwdasdas%22,%22id%22:%221%22%7D
```

This URI, with the brackets percent encoded as required by the spec, should satisfy the java code.

I'm guessing that JSON.stringify is doing what we would expect:

```
> JSON.stringify({"codingo":"qwdasdas","id":"1"})
'{"codingo":"qwdasdas","id":"1"}'
```

What doesn't make any sense to me, based on the information you provided, is why you are getting a query where QUOTATION MARK is getting percent encoded, but not LEFT CURLY BRACKET and RIGHT CURLY BRACKET.  Your URI looks like somebody decided to roll their own URI encoder, and didn't handle all of the "special characters" correctly.

A way to verify that it is a problem on your java script side, rather than the java running on the server, would be to look at the HTTP request being generated, and verify the value being used as the target-uri for the request: if the query has an invalid spelling in the request, then the server certainly has nothing to do with the problem (other than reporting it).